# What is the problem with importing this module?

Tags: python, module

I have a module called sinfun:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#sinfun.py

def newsin(x):
   return sin(x)/x
```

and I want to use it in this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from math import *
import sinfun

x = input("enter x: ")
x = float(x)
y = sinfun.newsin(x)
print(y)
```

What is the problem in this example and what must be done to make the code work?

Comment: Is there a problem, an error ? Show it because we see none. Where does come from `sin` in first file ?

Comment: Where are your files located relative to each other? What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

If you put 'from math import *' into sinfun.py, this works.  Would this be the preferred setup, making 'sinfun.py' a black box of sorts?  As written, I get an error that it couldn't find 'sin'.

Answer (score 1):

As was previously mentioned, it's because `sinfun.py` doesn't have access to your `math` import in; presumably, your main. The quick solution is to move the math import into `sinfun`.

However, you could also move `sinfun` to another folder (['packages'](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)) called, say `maths` and add an `__init__.py` which only contains `from math import *`, then from your main you could import `import maths.sinfun as sinfun` and your function would work as intended.

```
|   main.py
|
\---maths
        sinfun.py
        __init__.py
```